# How to avoid overlapping between logo div and menu div when page zooming?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two div-classes named .logo and .menu class within header-bottom class div.

```
<header class="header-bottom">
<div class="logo">
<a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="REVELATION" /></a>
</div>
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li class="current"><a href="#">homepage</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">site demo</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">full width</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Now the problem is, when I change my browser window or zooming, then the .logo and .menu classes contents overlapped with each other. If I set width in logo then the problem was solved but I want another simple approached to hole the whole .logo class div even if not having no contents.
box-sizing, positioning may solved the problem but how? I don't know.
[image]

[image]

```
*{
    margin:0 ;
    padding:0;
}

/* hedaer bottom*/
.header-bottom 
{
    padding-top:40px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.header-bottom .logo
{
    width:15%;
    float:left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header-bottom .menu
{
    width:85%;
    float:left;     
}
.header-bottom .menu ul
{
    list-style:none;
    float:right;
    margin-top:15px;
    padding-right:12px;
}
.header-bottom .menu ul li
{
    float:left; 
    padding-bottom:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ededed;
}
.header-bottom .menu ul li:last-child
{
    padding-right:0px;
}

.header-bottom .menu ul li a
{
    text-decoration:none;
    font-family:Georgia Regular;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#55415f;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    /* border-bottom:2px solid transparent;*/
}
.header-bottom .menu ul li a:hover
{
    padding-bottom:10px;
    border-bottom:2px solid #55415f;
}
.header-bottom .menu .current a
{
    border-bottom:2px solid #55415f;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: Why is setting `.logo image{width: 100%}` not a solution for you?

Comment: if my image missing by any way then the alternative text also overlapped with menu. Just want to know how to capture whole div when having no contents.As I set width 15% b ut not works when inspecting for image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start using Flexbox.

The `display: flex` set on the `.header-bottom` will make the `.logo` and `.menu` stay side-by-side, like *table cells*, and the `flex-grow: 1` set on the  `.menu` makes the `.menu` take the space left, that is not occupied by the `.logo`

Finally, with the `align-items: center` set on the `.header-bottom` you don't need top/bottom padding to center the `.logo` and the `.menu`, `align-items` does it for you, similar to what `vertical-align: middle` does to `inline` elements.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


/* hedaer bottom*/

.header-bottom {
  padding-top: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.header-bottom .logo {
  padding-right:10px;
}

.header-bottom .menu {
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.header-bottom .menu ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  list-style: none;
}

.header-bottom .menu ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ededed;
  padding-right:10px;
}

.header-bottom .menu ul li:last-child {
}

.header-bottom .menu ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Georgia Regular;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #55415f;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  /* border-bottom:2px solid transparent;*/
}

.header-bottom .menu ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #55415f;
}

.header-bottom .menu .current a {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #55415f;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-bottom">
  <div class="logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="REVELATION" /></a>
  </div>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li class="current"><a href="#">homepage</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">site demo</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">full width</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">portfolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">gallery</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">dropdown</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Comment: .header-bottom{  display: flex;}
.header-bottom .menu {flex-grow: 1;} This two solved my problem. But how I don't know? How it knows float left after another?

Comment: @ZishanCse Thanks ... and I updated my answer, and you can drop the `float`'s